# Am I using Latex/Mathjax right for coloring text?

Tags: html, latex, mathjax

I'm trying to use the latex commands for mathjax in my html code. I have the following commands in my body tag:

```
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\color[Hello world]{ABCDEF}
```

which can be seen in http://jsfiddle.net/gamea12/e6fna2bs/, but it doesn't seem to be working and is displayed as text for some reason. Can I get some help on how mathjax formatting works?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try something like

```
$${\rm\color[rgb]{1,0,0}Some~red~math}$$
```

in your document body, keeping in mind that MathJax is not a complete LaTeX authoring environment, only a means to display mathematics in HTML.

Comment: I have a few problems with this solution, mainly being that a. This doesn't seem to use the xcolor package, which means that colors like #ABCDEF aren't working either, as seen in http://jsfiddle.net/gamea12/e6fna2bs/1/. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger Thanks, but that's actually my own question. While trying to implement the answer given, I came across some trouble with the /usepackage{xcolor} and that's why I made this thread. I can try reasking it in a more aptly put way and deleting this thread, if necessary.

Comment: You should look at the other answer there which was given by MathJax's lead developer Davide Cervone.

Comment: I modified my answer to show the use of an RGB color. What I wanted to emphasize is that in MathJax you don't get to load LaTeX packages. You can include corresponding JavaScript files in the preamble, assuming such JavaScript files actually exist (e.g., AMSmath.js, AMSsymbols.js), as indeed you have loaded color.js this way in your example on JSFiddle.